# German uses a singular noun whereas english uses plural noun

Tags: noun

Reading Hammer's grammar and usage 4th edition, Page 30.

It's says that german uses a singular noun if more than one person is mentioned in the sense of items of clothing or parts of the body.

Hammer gives an example , "Ihnen klopfte das Herz" meaning "their hearts were beating".

Are there any other resources that could expand on this aspect of german?

Are there any exceptions to this rule ?

Comment: The *aspect* that you are looking for is: the appropriate description of biological fact. Humans have (normally) only one heart. The statement *Ihnen klopften die Herzen* would imply that each person had many hearts. For me, the true question is not why German uses singular (in accordance with biological fact), but why English uses plural (deviating from biological fact).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: "The statement *Ihnen klopften die Herzen* would imply that each person had many hearts." - That is not true. "Ihnen klopften die Herzen." can be legitimately interpreted in two (or even three) ways: 1) Each of them has one heart. 2) Each of them has several hearts. 3) All of them share an unspecified number of hearts. Likewise, "Ihnen klopfte das Herz." can be interpreted in two ways: 1) Each of them has one heart. 2) All of them share a single common heart. Which interpretation is correct can exclusively be derived from contextual knowledge.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Can you create an answer with this content? It is easier to format and can be upvoted that way....

Comment: @guidot: Not unless I know how to *answer* the question. So far, my comment merely confirms the premise of the question, but doesn't answer it.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Man sagt im Deutschen auch "Sie sattelten ihre Pferde", auch wenn jeder nur ein Pferd hat und nur eines sattelt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumption

> German uses a singular noun if more than one person is mentioned in the sense of items of clothing or parts of the body

is wrong. At least if you interpret it as an absolute proposition. Here are some counterexamples:

- In catholic masses there is a liturgic formula spoken by the priest:

  > Erhebet **die Herzen!** (English: *Lift up your hearts!*; Latin: *Sursum corda!*)
- Bible, Lukas 21:28:

  > Wenn aber dies anfängt zu geschehen, so richtet euch auf und erhebt **eure Häupter,** weil eure Erlösung naht.
- And of coarse you also find a lot of examples in the internet:

  > - Zeigt her **eure Nasen!**
  >   <sup>weekly magazine [Brigitte](https://www.brigitte.de/beauty/schoen/body-positivity--frauen-zeigen-ihre-nasen-11064090.html)</sup>
  > - Warum haben Männer **größere Nasen** als Frauen?
  >   <sup>German edition of [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.de/wissenschaft/2018/08/warum-haben-maenner-groessere-nasen-als-frauen)</sup>
  > - Indische Springameisen schrumpfen **ihre Gehirne**
  >   <sup>monthly magazine [GEO](https://www.geo.de/natur/tierwelt/indische-springameisen-schrumpfen-ihre-gehirne-30480054.html)</sup>
  > - Teenager verbrennen absichtlich **ihre Zungen**
  >   <sup>daily newspaper [heute](https://www.heute.at/s/glaetteisen-challenge-teenager-verbrennen-absichtlich-ihre-zungen-43903947)</sup>
  > - Warum messen Jungs **ihre Penise?**
  >   <sup>question&answer board [gutefrage.net](https://www.gutefrage.net/a/frage/warum-messen-jungs-ihre-penise)</sup>

---

Fact is, that in German we use both forms. Both forms are correct but the meaning differs in small nuances:

- **Singular**

  > Ihnen klopfte **das Herz.**

  Here you claim that the heart of every single person beats. You put the focus on the fact that everybody has just one heart. And this single and therefor precious heart was beating.
- **Plural**

  > Ihnen klopften **die Herzen.**

  Here you say, that everybody's heart was beating. You put the focus on the fact, that this is something that happens with all hearts.

So, you use singular, when you want to point out that the owner's relationship to their singular organ is important and you use plural if it's important that something happens to everybody.

Comment: Careful, older (like here liturgical or biblical texts) often use outdated or today uncommon turns of phrase.

Comment: @vonbrand: But modern newspapers and magazines don't.